# Setting up Environment for PayPal Api

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to set up a Java environment for using the PayPal sandbox Api.

I've tried to read the documentation but i can't figure it out.

From where can i start?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'set up a Java environment', but here's a sketch of how to proceed with a PayPal Checkout integration.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls); there is a Checkout-Java-SDK you can use. These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The capture route should (on success) store the payment details in your database  (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) before it does the return.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Preston

i know my question is a bit generic, but i really don't know where to start.

I need to find out how to get payment reports from PayPal.

Your answer is a start point form me.

Thanks again